# Robolectric "INTERNET permission is required"

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm getting this error when I create an activity with Robolectric:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INTERNET permission is required.`

This is what I'm doing:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
    sdk = TestConfig.MIN_SDK_UNIT_TESTS,
    manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class ATest {
  @Test public void testTrackDoNotAskMeAgainSelected() throws Exception {
    final AnActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(AnActivity.class).create().get();
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Our current setup, We have this manifests:

```
app/src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml
app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
app/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I found that `debug` is executed instead of `test`, so that's why the permission in `app/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml` is ignored.

Comment: Why do you need manifest in `Config`? If there are no reasons remove it. I think the issue is that Robolectric doesn't use your AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

Please check to use the AndroidManifest in debugTest flavor(folder) for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the SDK [in my case Segment] that needs INTERNET Permission as a separate function as below -

```
@VisibleForTesting()
public void initializeSegmentSdk() {
    // Create an analytics client with the given context and Segment write key.
    Analytics analytics = new Analytics.Builder(this, "xyz")
    // Enable this to record certain application events automatically!
    .trackApplicationLifecycleEvents()
    // Enable this to record screen views automatically!
    .recordScreenViews()
    .build();

    // Set the initialized instance as a globally accessible instance.
    Analytics.setSingletonInstance(analytics);
}
```

Create a Shadow of the class that holds the above method and override this method to return empty.

OR

You can also use **Mockito** to return nothing whenever `initializeSegmentSdk()` method is called

Answer (score -2):

add this to your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I have two manifest files, here: `app/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml` and here: `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, the one I add in the `@Config` has the permission, I thought both were merged

Comment: Did adding the permission to the test manifest help? What are you using in the test manifest/why can't you just use the main one?

Comment: @colabug because we use Dagger2 to inject different stuff when testing, so we have a `app/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml` with this: `<application android:name=".TestRideApp"/>`

Comment: Can you flesh out your set up a bit in the original question? Might be helpful for those stumbling on this question in the future.

Comment: You don't need additional manifest to tweaking your application in the tests. Please read this http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/

Comment: @colabug I edit the question with all manifest files we have, and this weird behaviour about that `debug` is execute instead of `test`.